# 4.1.2 vs 4.4.4 - any improvements re general speed and app caching?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.1-jelly-bean, multitasking

I am growing frustrated with the following behaviours of Android 4.1.2, which has been running my rooted Samsung S3 I9300 for two years now:

1) When switching between already-open apps, more often than not going back to an app that had some data loaded (e.g. address looked up in GoogleMaps, page loaded in Firefox etc) results in the app starting all over from its initial screen and thus losing the input I had given it just minutes ago 
2) Generally very sluggish operation, although I am careful to limit the number of apps installed/running
3) When connecting to a new WiFi network for the first time, the phone restarts (this has only been happening for a few months)

Since I have no real reason to invest in a new phone (new features in S4,S5 and S6 don't seem that appealing), I was considering just doing an OS upgrade, and since Lollipop seems to not be rated well by users, KitKat 4.4.4 seems the likely candidate. 
I am wondering whether anyone who has used my current version (4.1.2) can comment on whether any of the above behaviours are corrected in v4.4.4, in particular whether the general performance/speed is better in 4.4.4 (or other KitKat versions) as compared to 4.1.2 (or other Jellybean versions), and whether app caching actually works during multitasking.

Comment: Granted my phone is a little different (Galaxy S3 SCH-I535) it updated to 4.4.2 right when I bought it new earlier this year. On this model running 4.4.2, I haven't experienced any of the bugs you mention.

Comment: I bet, though, that 1) is really thought of as a "feature, not a bug", if a very annoying "feature"!

Comment: Back to number 1, how are you switching between apps? Are you using the "Recent Apps" menu or some other way? I switch through open apps (occasionally, as I tend to not have multiple apps running at once) using the "Recent Apps" menu and also have no issues.

Comment: I use the same way: long press Home button, and use RecentApps menu. Although from the OS' point of view, it's probably the same if you just start an app from the main app menu. Both methods lead to a fresh start of the app - oblivious to its previous state, which is exasperating. So just to confirm, you haven't noticed this happening in 4.4.2?

Comment: (ALthough if you say you've only used it on 4.4.2, you are probably unable to comment on speed&app caching changes as compared to 4.1.2)

Comment: No, I haven't noticed the issue you are having. When I switch between apps, both on my Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Tab 4 running KitKat, they return as I left them. Alternatively, I'm also running Jellybean on a couple of other devices (HTC Incredible, HTC Rezound, Galaxy Tab 1) and app switching works as expected. I cannot say that performance speed is noticeably faster between Jellybean and KitKat, but the latter definitely runs smoother.

Comment: I also totally agree with you that there is little need to upgrade to a new device. The Galaxy S3 is virtually a perfect phone and the new versions add no must-have features. I would have no reservations about upgrading the OS to KitKat.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. If app switching doesn't the reset the app's status in your phones running Jellybean, this suggests the problem is on my side. I know there is an option specifically for this issue under the Developer/debugging options, but in my case the problem is not from there. What version of Jellybean do you have installed exactly?

Comment: I have Jellybean running on two different devices. The first is an HTC Incredible running 4.1.1 (cm_inc-userdebug4.1.1JRO03eng.scott.20120908.223621 test keys). The second is a Galaxy Tab 1 but I'll have to get back to you with a version number.

Comment: Just for future reference, I got hold of a phone running Android 4.4.4, and problem 1) is exactly the same, therefore it seems not really worth doing the upgrade. Disgraceful work by Google on this OS.